# SignalR WPF StateChange Issues

Tags: c#, signalr, dispatcher, signalr.client

I am writing a little WPF application to test some SignalR code. Everything works from what I have written, but I have stumbled across something which I am unsure of.

I have created an event handler for the `HubConnection` `StateChanged` event;

```
_hub.StateChanged += (change) =>
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("hubConnection.StateChanged {0} => {1}", change.OldState, change.NewState);

    if (change.NewState == ConnectionState.Connecting)
    {
        statusCallBack callBack = new statusCallBack(UpdateStatus);
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(callBack, "hubConnection.StateChanged");
    }
    if (change.NewState == ConnectionState.Connected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
        statusCallBack callBack = new statusCallBack(UpdateStatus);
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(callBack, "hubConnection.StateChanged");
    }
};
```

With my Delegate method `statusCallBack` and method being;

```
delegate void statusCallBack(string msg);

private void UpdateStatus(string msg)
{
    if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() == true)
    {                
        this.tbStatus.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " --- " + msg);
        this.tbStatus.CaretIndex = this.tbStatus.Text.Length;
        this.tbStatus.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

Now I am probably missing something really obvious here, but when in the `StateChanged` handler I check for `ConnectionState.Connecting` and output the message to my Label it works fine.

Then when the SignalR HubConnection state then changes to `ConnectionState.Connected` and I try to Invoke the delegate, the WPF app just locks up.

It will output to the console fine, and check to see if `change.NewState == ConnectionState.Connected`, then will output "hello" to the console, but then just freezes.

If I debug the app, when it gets to within the Connected `if` statement, the object `change.NewState` and `change.OldState` have the error message below.

[image]

[View larger image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2jEb.jpg)

I am lost as to why it works within the first if statement, but not the second. Also why it is able to output the correct values to the console?

Even if I comment out the initial `if` statement to check for `Connecting` it will still freeze when `Connected`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common deadlock problem when calling back to the UI from an event.

Try using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` rather than `Invoke`.

As quoted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009174/dispatcher-invoke-vs-begininvoke-confusion) thread:

> When you use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke it means that it schedules the
>   given action for execution in the UI thread at a later point in time,
>   and then returns control to allow the current thread to continue
>   executing. Invoke blocks the caller until the scheduled action
>   finishes.

As a side-note: MVVM Light has a very useful helper called [`DispatcherHelper`](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/SL5/html/5af6dede-4a22-2eb2-d0fa-5af0f2fe4fe5.htm) that is not only compatible with virtually everything (WPF, WinRT, SL, etc.), but very simple to use. It helps you automatically dispatch calls back to the UI. If nothing else, it may be helpful to use the NUGet package JUST for this feature.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I can now move on with my life :P I will check out MVVM Light.

Comment: yes! there is definitely something wrong when you get the error `This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.'
` despite `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread == System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Thread` being true