# Update UI from an Async method

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have this method what called from an Async method

```
private void SocketConnected(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Some code


    connectedLabel.Content = "Connected";
}
```

And the `connectedLabel.Content = "Connected";` throws an error. How can I update this from this method? I've seen a few post saying use Invoke, however, that gives me an error that label doesn't have a Invoke method.

EDIT:

From looking at Dispatcher as mentioned in the comments I've got this which works.

```
    private string message;
    public void UpdateConnected()
    {
        connectedLabel.Content = message;
    }

    private void SocketConnected(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Some stuff

        message = "Connected";
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(this.UpdateConnected), DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
```

Is that the correct usage of the Dispatcher?

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling this? If you're calling it from an `async` method.. you should be `await`'ing a result..

Comment: What UI toolkit are you using? What `Invoke`-like method to use depends on the UI toolkits as e.g. WinForms and WPF provide different means of synchronizing oneself back into the UI thread. Add an appropriate tag, please.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead This is using event based asynchrony, not task based asynchrony.

Comment: Oh, so it is (you would think the method signature would make me realise that). My mistake.

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke should fix your problem

Comment: I don't have the Async code, I'm using a WebSocket library which has `ws.ConnectAsync();`, and when it connects that above method is called. If I use `ws.Connect();` I don't get the error so I can only assume it's to do with the Async part.

Comment: @TomHart It's still important for us to know what UI framework you're using.

Comment: @AD.Net: [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was only introduced with WPF, and we don't know whether the OP is using WPF yet (even though the label having a `Content` property makes this likely).

Comment: Sorry I'm new to C#, how do I know what Framework I'm using? I'm using .NET 4.5 and my main class is `MainWindow : Window`, I don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: I've updated my question now, am I now going along the right lines?

Comment: @TomHart Would you mark some of the replies as answer?

Comment: Sorry I forgot, SO wouldn't let me when I posted this. Done it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your edit, unless you have a need for the async method to carry on with whatever it has left to do *before* the label is updated, you can just use `Dispatcher.Invoke` rather than `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

If you're interested in the difference: [Dispatcher Invoke(...) vs BeginInvoke(...) confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009174/dispatcher-invoke-vs-begininvoke-confusion)

Comment: That's cool to know about Invoke vs BeginInvoke, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension method and use async/await

```
await socket.ConnectTaskAsync(host,port);
connectedLabel.Content = "Connected";
```

---

```
public static class SocketExtensions
{
    public static Task ConnectTaskAsync(this Socket socket, string host, int port)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                         socket.BeginConnect(host, port, null, null),
                         socket.EndConnect);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP appears to be using an event based asynchronous model, which won't work with `FromAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just... ?

```
// WPF
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label.Content = "my label"));
```

or

```
// WinForms
BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label.Text = "my label"));
```