# MethodInvoker in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

What is the alternative of MethodInvoker in wpf
In `windows form`I use this code

```
private void msg()
{
   if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(msg));
   else
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData;
```

In WPF I am using `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` instead of `this.InvokeRequired` but there is no `Dispatcher.MethodInvoke()` or `Dispatcher.Inovke.MethodInvoke()` in wpf
If someone convert mycode to WPF it will be great

**Edit:**

Unknown Characters
[image]

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644079/how-can-i-use-the-dispatcher-invoke-in-wpf-change-controls-from-non-main-thread and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009174/dispatcher-invoke-vs-begininvoke-confusion

Comment: Also here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I saw all the answered question but I didn't find the correct answer for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you may use this:

```
public static class TextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void CheckAppendText(this TextBoxBase textBox, string msg, bool waitUntilReturn = false)
    {
        Action append = () => textBox.AppendText(msg);
        if (textBox.CheckAccess())
        {
            append();
        }
        else if (waitUntilReturn)
        {
            textBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(append);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(append);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like

```
    private void msg()
    {
        textBox1.CheckAppendText(Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData);
    }
```

When updating the UI from a background thread, you should generally use `BeginInvoke` rather than `Invoke` to avoid the possibility of a hang waiting for the UI thread to process the request while that thread is in turn waiting for something from the background thread.

Comment: Its working fine appending the textbox data but also appending lot of unknown character signs

Comment: Check the Picture above

Comment: @UzairAli - I cannot reproduce your problem.  Perhaps the bad characters are coming from `readData`?  If `readData` is actually binary then you could get that effect.  You can see the contents of `readData` in Visual Studio or by calling `Debug.WriteLine(readData)`.

Comment: Nope I checked `readData` just before executing this method its totally fine I used this code   
     `private void msg()
      {
         MessageBox.Show(readData);
        textBox1.CheckAppendText(Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData);
      }`

Comment: Oh yes this is the problem my side. `MessageBox.Show(readData.Text)` is showing the text correctly but when I check the length of that text with this `MessageBox.Show(readData.Text.Length)` it is ridiculously long (10k words).

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic corresponding code for MethodInvoker and UI thread in WPF:

```
if (control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
  UpdateUI();
else
  control.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(UpdateUI));
```