# Why doesn't Dispatcher.BeginInvoke take an Action as a parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf

Dispatcher.[Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) method can take either a [Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc647509.aspx) or [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh199416.aspx) instance as a parameter.
But Dispatcher.[BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx) method doesn't accept an Action instance; it supports only [Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc190824.aspx).

It forces me to cast a lambda expression to Action in case of BeginInvoke.
For example:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Title = "foo"); // success
// Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Title = "foo"); // error
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Title = "foo")); // success
```

Is there any reason why Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method couldn't take an Action parameter?

Comment: You'd have to ask the API designers to know for sure, no one else can tell. Maybe they just didn't think about it. That sucks, but you can define an extension method to circumvent it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009174/dispatcher-invoke-vs-begininvoke-confusion

Comment: Microsoft programmers started writing WPF code in June of 2002, .NET 1.0 was barely released.  Nothing you can't fix with an extension method.

Comment: You might want to use `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` introduced in .Net 4.5. That should serve all your needs and makes live a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

It's a design decision. Since WPF came with .NET 3.0 and probably WPF was developed during some years, maybe delegates like `Action`, `Action<T>`... or `Func<T>`... weren't added in early .NET 3.0 alphas so they left the code using their own delegate.

In the other hand, you argue you need to perform a *cast* while you should instantiate `Action` instead:

```
// This is possible!
Delegate d1 = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("hello world"));

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { /* ---do stuff--- */ }));
```