# Issue with Dispatcher in threads WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with threads and dispatcher in wpf, I created a thread which in certain cases bind class(wpf page control) to Main.MainContent.Content, only works the first time, then it doesn't work. I am a beginner in this topic, so I am asking for understanding and a thorough explanation. Let me add that I read a bit about DispatcherPriority Enum and tried to replace BeginInvoke with Invoke.

[image: problem preview 1]

[image: problem preview 2]

Comment: Okay, you have a problem. But what is your question?

Comment: I want this thread to be executed every time, not just the first, after the first execution, when the program reaches the dispatcher it doesn't work.

Comment: Check explanation between Invoke and BeginInvoke: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009174/dispatcher-invoke-vs-begininvoke-confusion

Comment: I checked again, added thread.sleep (1000) and checked begininvoke and invoke and still don't work

Comment: Why are you invoking, while on the dispatcher thread it self?

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Include it in text with code formatting instead.

Comment: How else can I change content from a thread?

Comment: Whats wrong with a `DispatcherTimer`?

Comment: If you want to work from a thread, you have to prepare the data in classes and assign them later via a Dispatcher.Invoke

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing one line:

```
MainWindow.Main.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { MainWindow.Main.MainContent.Content = new AcceptedPage(); }));
```

on:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = new AcceptedPage(); }));
```